How Can I Reduce Delay When Sending File Contents to Kafka Producer Using Script?
I want to write a bash script to constantly add new files to a folder and use cat to send the file contents to a Kafka producer with:
    cat $FILEPATH |$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test 

But it generally takes more than 4 seconds to finish the execution. I am wondering if there's any way to write a script to automatically add new messages to a Kafka producer with less delay.
I also tried to echo the contents of the file to the producer instead, but the delay still exists. So, I think it has something to do with the producer command.

The JVM needs to startup, yes, but that shouldn't take very long. You could try installing kcat command instead, but you should first try without using cat
kafka-console-producer ... < $FILEPATH

Otherwise, you're running the producer command for each line of the file Useless use of cat?

automatically add new messages to a Kafka producer

This doesn't require a shell script. You can use Kafka Connect, Filebeat, Fluentbit, etc to watch a directory of files automatically and produce their lines to Kafka

Thanks, @OneCricketeer! I tried replacing cat with < but it still takes more than 4 sec to execute the command. What I actually want to do here is pipe my auto generated data into a Kafka topic. I tried to first add data to a Flink table using the filesystem connector, then sink the table to another table with a Kafka connector. I found that the data can be shown in a Kafka consumer in real-time. So I'm thinking about giving up on piping data directly from files since what matters is to pipe data into the topics. Do you know any other way to add auto-generated test data into a Kafka topic?

I don't have experience with Flink. You can try the options I listed, if you have files. If you just want to generate some random data, take a look at ShadowTraffic
